# Is it necessary to use the induction assumption in an induction proof?

Tags: probability, induction

Is it necessary to use the induction assumption in an induction proof?

Reason to ask is that I was doing a proof about Markov chains:

---

Prove that $(X_k, Y_{k+1})_{k \geq 1}$ is Markov chain.
$X_0=x_0$ is given and in every round ($k \geq 1$) one first generates $Y_k \sim q(X_{k-1}, \cdot)$ (where $q$ is a probability distribution), then either sets $X_k=Y_k$ or rejects $Y_k$ as invalid and sets $X_k=Y_{k-1}$.

By induction:

$X_0 = x_0$
$Y_1 \sim q(X_0, \cdot)$
$P(Y_1 | X_0)$ OK.

Assume $n=k$ i.e. $P(Y_{k} | Y_0, ..., Y_{k-1})=P(Y_k | Y_{k-1})$
holds.

Prove $n=k+1$ holds:

on the $k$th round $X_k=Y_k$ or reject $Y_k$ and set $X_k=Y_{k-1}$, in either case $X_k$ is the value of the previous r.v.

on the $k+1$th one picks $Y_{k+1} \sim q(X_{k}, \cdot)$ 
so  $Y_{k+1}$ only depends on the previous r.v.

---

It seems like I didn't need to use the induction assumption at all?

Or perhaps I need to use something to split $P(Y_{k+1} | Y_1, ...,  X_k)$ to smaller parts that may include $P(Y_k | Y_{k-1})$, the induction step.

Comment: You must use the inductive assumption somewhere in the inductive step or your proof is not inductive.

Comment: @Landuros That's not true.

Comment: @5xum But then you might not be able to go from $k$ to $k+1$? The way I've learnt it is that you **must** use it regardless whether you can do it or not.

Comment: @mavavilj it would be useful to first write the statement you are trying to prove

Comment: If you don't use the inductive assumption, then it isn't a proof by induction. This doesn't imply that the proof is false, though.

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud Yes, that is a better way of putting it.

Comment: @Landuros I can prove the statement "For all $n\in\mathbb N: n=n$ using induction without using the inductive assumption. For $n=1$, $1=1$ because of the law of identity. Now assume $n=n$. Then, from the law of identity, $n+1=n+1$, therefore the statement $n=n\implies n+1=n+1$ is true.

Comment: @5xum I see what you mean. However, you haven't shown that $n = n \implies n+1=n+1$ because you simply haven't linked the two statements together via any inductive hypothesis. Please correct me if I'm wrong, I am a little confused too. If you did use the inductive hypothesis, you would say $LHS = n+1 = n+1 = RHS$, and in between you subbed in $n=n$. Similar question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/953509/induction-proof-without-explictly-using-the-induction-hypothesis

Comment: Remember than the induction step in the induction proof amounts to proving that $P(n) \to P(n+1)$, for every $n$. If we have a proof of $P(n+1)$ we can use the *tautology*: $P(n+1) \to (P(n) \to P(n+1))$ and *modus ponens* to derive $P(n) \to P(n+1)$. Conclusion: the proof is fine.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, an induction proof uses induction principle, an axiom of Natural numbers in a specific definition. In order to use it, one can suppose a subset of $\mathbb{N}$, say $S_p$ based upon some property p of a natural number (For example, p: n is a even number or an odd number). Now, according to principle, if $0 \in S_p$, and $n\in S_p \Rightarrow (n+1)\in S_p$, only then $S_p \cong \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @Landuros I proved $Y$ is a true statement, therefore I proved $X\implies Y$ is a true statement no matter what $X$ is. Now sure, you could argue that this isn't a "true" proof by induction, but from a purely mathematical position, it *is* a proof by induction.

Answer (score 1):

If you can prove it without using the inductive assumption, then that's just fine!

I don't have the background to comment on your specific proof, but here is one that I ran into:

[image]

OK, so here I proved that every natural number other than $0$ has a predecessor on the basis of the Peano Axioms.  On line $6$ I have proven the base, and on lines $7$ through $11$ I prove the step, with the inductive hypothesis on line $7$. Note that I never end up using this inductive hypothesis. In fact, I don't use any of the Peano axioms except the inductive axiom. And even more strikingly: without induction I could not have proven this, because the statement does *not* follow from the Peano axioms without the inductive axiom. In other words, here is an example of a non-trivial (necessary!) use of induction, that did not use the inductive hypothesis.

Comment: I think my specific example is entirely interpretable from what I've given. Since in either case the $Y_{k+1}$ variable depends on the previous variable only. But I don't see where I need the inductive assumption here.

Comment: @mavavilj I believe you ... I'm just not at all familiar with Markov chains. But like I said, it's perfectly possible to do a proof by induction without ever using the inductive hypothesis. I just added an example to my post.

Comment: @Bram28 I believe Peano Axioms are the *only* exception. Every other inductive proof requires the use of the inductive hypothesis. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/953511/432780

Comment: @Landuros: See Mauro's comment to the main question. I know you want to believe this, but it's just not true. What *is* true is that an inductive proof (i.e., one that uses the axiom of induction somewhere) that *doesn't* use the inductive hypothesis can generally be transformed to a non-inductive proof. But that doesn't make the inductive proof itself non-inductive.

Comment: @JohnHughes Thanks for clearing that up. I guess it'll take a while for me to totally accept it.